# Removing blocks of text with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove large blocks of text from a file using python. Each block of text begins with

/translation="SOMETEXT"

Ending with the second quote.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Use a regular expression. I'm not much into those but it's just a hint into the right direction.

Comment: Try the re module, use some regex tester it will make tests easier (http://ksamuel.pythonanywhere.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use re.sub like this:

```
import re
re.sub("/translation=\".*?\" ", "", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance doesn't matter, you could do something like this.  Regular expressions would probably be faster, but this is simpler.

```
def remtxt(s,startstr,endstr):
        while startstr in s:
                startpos=s.index(startstr)
                try:
                        endpos=s.index(endstr,startpos+len(startstr))+len(endstr)
                except:
                        return
                s=s[:startpos]+s[endpos:]
        return s

new_string=remtxt(my_string,'/translation="','"')
```